# Apply function to a column in dataframe - python

Tags: python

I wrote a function to eliminate spaces of a value in my dataframe.

```
def eliminate_space(words):
    return words.replace(' ', '')
```

Now I want to apply that function to each row in my 'words' column of my dataframe.

```
df['words']=df['words'].apply(eliminate_space(words))
```

It's saying the name 'words' is not defined.  How do I adjust my code to be able to apply the function to each value in that column of my dataframe?

Comment: Can you explain it more? or else post full code

Comment: In my df table, I have multiple columns.  One of them is called 'words'.  For example, 'Hello there', 'Good bye'.  I want to get rid of the spaces.  I was asked to write a function to apply to each row of my df table to eliminate all spaces if there are any.

Comment: do you want it to apply only to words column or else all other columns too?

Comment: It could be to any column, but i was just specifying my columns 'words' here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `lambda` for that column of `row`:

```
df['words']=df['words'].apply(lambda row: eliminate_space(row))
```

Testing with example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words':['word is 1', 'word is 2', 'word is 3']})
print(df)
```

Initial dataframe:

```
     words
0  word is 1
1  word is 2
2  word is 3
```

Using function:

```
df['words']=df['words'].apply(lambda row: eliminate_space(row))
```

Result:

```
     words
0  wordis1
1  wordis2
2  wordis3
```

Comment: Thanks! I forgot to think about iterating (using lambda) to each row

Comment: Great! `Happy Coding` .